# Class property with two different types

Tags: c#, struct, interface, multiple-inheritance

I've a class with a property, foo, that it was initially defined as bool. Now i need to manage it as a new Class FooClass, but i need to not broke backcompatibility with previous value

I tried to achieve this by doing

```
[JsonProperty("foo")]
    public object Foo { 
        get { return Foo is bool ? new FooClass { Value = "example" } : Foo; }
        set {
            if (value is not bool && value is not FooClass && value is not null) throw new InvalidPropertyException($"Foo cannot be of type ${value.GetType}");
            if (value is bool) Foo = new FooClass { Value = "example" };
            Foo = value;
    }
```

But i don't like it because i'm declaring property as object. Is there a way to use a interface and handle both type?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by backcompatibility? Deserializing old Json data? Source code compatibility? Binary compatibility?

Comment: Deserializing old Json data

Comment: You should be able to use the new type `FooClass` for the property and handle old documents via a  a [JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)

Comment: If posiible, you might want to override the implicit conversion operator from `FooClass` to `bool` and from `bool` to `FooClass`.

Comment: @KlausGütter i can manage it by using Jsonconverter, but there is a lot of code that uses the class, so i am trying to find a solution that works by using the class, independently from where it comes

Comment: You can register the JsonConverter using the [JsonConverterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterattribute) directly at the property.